# About exporting products in magento

Tags: magento

I read many tutorials about using magento but i am still no sure about the exporting products. Are products  lost from the store after export?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

Products are not deleted after export from magento. You can export the products in CSV or XML but CSV is best. After making changes when you import the CSV again Product information will be updated in the magento. If you add new products rows in the CSV then new products will be created.

You can export in magento from backend. For Export products follow the below steps:

1. Login in backend
2. From Top Navigation `System` >> `Import/Export` >> `Dataflow – Profiles`

Here you will find the profiles for import export products. You can create your own profile as well like you only want to export product titles and description. For this you can check `Export Product Stocks` Profile